# Frequency response of BJT frequencies with CE bypassed

Tags: bjt, frequency

In a lot of reference I see divergence like Zce = RE || (beta re + Rb || Rs) / (beta + 1) etc.
$$Z_{ce} = R_E || \left(\frac{\beta.r_e + R_b || R_s}{\beta + 1}\right)$$

See [link 1](https://youtu.be/Fq8WXls2dZI?t=1033), [link 2](https://youtu.be/OjKDx_q9VZQ?t=97), [link 3](https://youtu.be/daim-F5Vshk?t=886), [link 4](https://youtu.be/zQDPDIcUjgQ?t=489)

but from a trivial example I get

Zce = RE || (beta re + Rb || Rs) / (beta)
$$Z_{ce} = R_E || \left(\frac{\beta .r_e + R_b || R_s}{\beta}\right)$$

[image: Frequency response of BJT frequencies with CE bypassed]

Note : with that, i get the same result than [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/289126/low-frequency-response-of-bjt-amplifiereffect-of-bypass-capacitor) with the result of  Electronic Devices and Circuit Theory, by Boylestad and Nashelsky.

Note : I know with beta >= 100 it is the same but i like to have a rigourous demonstration.

Do you think it is a good reasoning here ?

Comment: Why bypass **C**ollector **E**mitter? What's that all about then? What has your question got to do with the links at the top? Do we need to read these first? If so, then ermm no.

Comment: That the correct equation is \$Z = R_E|| (r_e + \frac{R_B||R_S}{\beta 
+1})\$

Comment: Because in \$\beta r_e\$ is just an approximation the correct version is \$r_\pi = (\beta +1)r_e\$

Comment: \$r_e = \frac{dV_{BE}}{dI_E} = \frac{V_T}{I_E}\$  https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/429716/arriving-at-a-wrong-output-impedance-for-a-bjt-emitter-follower-configuration-ci/429726#429726

Comment: Did you notice the mistake in your analysis?

Answer (score 4):

Solution:

1. The error done is that it is necessary to include all the branches of the current sources (ic was forgotten).
2. Another error is that since

[image]

to get

[image]

a bad representation of the current branches which does not respect the transistor (with its currents ie, ic, ib) gives an unusable diagram

[image]

[fig. 1] is the good choice.

[fig. 2] it makes no sense.

So the solution is [fig. 1] and you get

[image]

thus the calculation of **z1** gives

[image]

and finally you can give this representation

[image]

and for the calculation of **Z** you do not have to worry about the current flowing in Re nor in Z1.

Likewise, you must remember of considering the BJT with its current on its ports (ie, ib, ic) so make the extensions of the wires with their currents.

- Case of a good calculation from RE : put the pen between RE and ie : you'll see it's RE || Z1. In this case, you can calculate Z1 with the branch ib, ic :

[image]

- Case of a bad calculation of Z1 :

[image]

Likewise, the BJT with its current on its ports (ie, ib, ic) so make the extensions of the wires with their currents.
In theses pictures you'll see a demonstration with \$ r_e \$ and \$ \pi \$ model.

Demonstration with \$ r_e \$ (or T) model :
[image: re model]

Demonstration with \$ \pi \$ model (\$ \pi \$ model obtained with the T model) :
[image: pi model]

Comment: Is this an answer to your question? If not it belongs as an edit to the original question and this post should be deleted. Please use capital letters at the start of sentences and punctuation marks (`.`) at the end..

Comment: I'm glad that you manage to figure it out.